# NULL pointer with boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, null, pointers, shared-ptr

What's the equivalent to the following:

```
std::vector<Foo*> vec;
vec.push_back(NULL);
```

when dealing with `boost::shared_ptr`? Is it the following code?

```
std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > vec;
vec.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<Foo>());
```

Note: I may push back a lot of such objects. Should I declare a global static `nullPtr` object somewhere? That way only one of them would have to be constructed:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> nullPtr;
```

Comment: good news from the next C++ standard: there, you can write "vec.emplace_back();" and get a null pointer append :)

Comment: Consider using `boost::ptr_vector` which requires less overhead.

Answer (score 54):

Your suggestion (calling the `shared_ptr<T>` constructor with no argument) is correct. (Calling the constructor with the value 0 is equivalent.)  I don't think that this would be any slower than calling `vec.push_back()` with a pre-existing `shared_ptr<T>`, since construction is required in both cases (either direct construction or copy-construction).

But if you want "nicer" syntax, you could try the following code:

```
class {
public:
    template<typename T>
    operator shared_ptr<T>() { return shared_ptr<T>(); }
} nullPtr;
```

This declares a single global object `nullPtr`, which enables the following natural syntax:

```
shared_ptr<int> pi(new int(42));
shared_ptr<SomeArbitraryType> psat(new SomeArbitraryType("foonly"));

...

pi = nullPtr;
psat = nullPtr;
```

Note that if you use this in multiple translation units (source files), you'll need to give the class a name (e.g. `_shared_null_ptr_type`), move the definition of the `nullPtr` object to a separate .cpp file, and add `extern` declarations in the header file where the class is defined.

Comment: nice idea dude. i had to +1 that :p but note the answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395685/how-do-you-choose-between-a-singleton-and-an-unnamed-class/395738#395738

Comment: Thanks guys. :) Looking at litb's post suggests that the class should really be named though.

Comment: some silly names: nullPtrT, NullPtrType, nullPtr_t . whatever :) i found they append a _t when there is only one instance of something (like, nothrow_t and nullptr_t).

Comment: another idea what to do when different TUs are involved: for avoiding static initialization fiasco you could also create a nullPtr() function, that returns an object of your null class. so you don't run into initialization order problems when something of a different TU uses your null object.

Comment: @litb: *In practice* the fiasco isn't a problem here, since the only thing that's ever called is the conversion operator, and that doesn't care if the object has been initialised or not. Alternatively you could even have per-TU static instances. (Just looking for ways to avoid function-call syntax!)

Comment: r_random_hacker, oh right. i forgot that it isn't the actual shared_ptr. yeah in practice there are probably no problems regarding that fiasco. i even think it is a POD so it is not even a problem theoretical (so it has no dynamic initialization). so never mentioned my "idea" before. silly litb :)

Comment: @litb: Yeah I guess it actually is a POD!  A pretty strange one mind you... :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker:  Extremely clever and kinda cool, but doesn't this seem like going a bit overboard?  There's a much simpler and cleaner solution just using `typedef`.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks, maybe it is going overboard. But I like that it works for any type.

Comment: Why not just do `pi.reset()`?

Comment: Or even use nullptr on modern compilers - see my answer (I realize, of course, that nullptr didn't exist in 2009 :)

Answer (score 18):

Well, this is legal:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> foo;  /* don't assign */
```

And in this state, it doesn't point to anything.  You can even test this property:

```
if (foo) {
    // it points to something
} else {
    // no it doesn't
}
```

So why not do this:

```
std::vector < shared_ptr<Foo> > vec;
vec.push_back (shared_ptr<Foo>);   // push an unassigned one
```

Answer (score 9):

In C++0x, you can simply convert from `nullptr` to `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Foo> > vec;
vec.push_back(nullptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could declare a global `nullPtr` for `shared_ptr<Foo>`. But if you pollute the global namespace, what would you call the global `nullPtr` for `shared_ptr<Bar>`?

Typically I declare the null ptr as a static in the class of the pointer.

```
#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>

class Foo; // forward decl
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
class Foo
{
public:
    static FooPtr Null;
}
...
// define static in cpp file
FooPtr Foo::Null;
...
// use Foo Null
vec.push_back(Foo::Null);
```

That way each class has a static Null.

Comment: You can get a more natural syntax by using a templated conversion operator on a global variable.  <plug>See my answer...</plug> :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something which I think is a bit simpler and works just fine

( remember that `typedef` is your friend ):

```
#include    <cstdlib>
#include    <vector>
#include    <iostream>
#include    <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_ptr< std::vector<char> > CharVecHandle;

inline CharVecHandle newCharVec(std::vector<char>::size_type size) {
    return CharVecHandle(new std::vector<char>(size));
}

inline CharVecHandle newCharVec(void) {
    return CharVecHandle();
}

int main ( void )
{
    CharVecHandle cvh = newCharVec();

    if (cvh == NULL) 
        std::cout << "It's NULL" << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "It's not NULL" << std::endl;

    std::vector< CharVecHandle > cvh_vec;

    cvh_vec.push_back(newCharVec(64));
    cvh_vec.push_back(newCharVec());

    // or call the NULL constructor directly
    cvh_vec.push_back(CharVecHandle());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Sure, a `typedef` is nicer to look at than `boost::shared_ptr<Foo>`, and the OP seems to be concerned only with a single type `Foo`, in which case `typedef` fits nicely. If you want to avoid a proliferation of `typedef`s for different smart pointer types, my approach is better I think. Not sure what you're trying to demonstrate with your `newCharVec()` functions though, can you explain?

Comment: @j_random_hacker:  The purpose of the `newCharVec` functions is the same as the typedef, convenience and consistency.  Less characters to type and consistency in creating real objects and NULL objects.  The thing is, that even if I was using the template method, I would still probably create a typedef.  Coming from a `C` background whenever I see an overly complicated type declaration my first instinct is to typedef it.  Taking that into account, I'm not sure if there's really an objective reason to pick one method or the other, it may be an issue of style or personal preference.

Comment: Well, one reason to prefer my approach is that, because my `nullPtr` is type-agnostic, it will work in function templates when manipulating variables whose type is unknown, while yours won't. E.g. I can write a function template `template <typename T> push_a_null_ptr(vector<shared_ptr<T> >& v) { v.push_back(nullPtr); }`, which will work for all types `T`. I admit it's not a huge upside, but I don't see any downsides.

Comment: Um, maybe I misinterpreted your last comment -- I thought you were comparing your approach to my approach, but maybe you were really comparing your approach to the OP's "starting point" approach of just spelling out the full `shared_ptr<Foo>()` each time?  If the latter then I agree your approach is nicer, I'd rather look at a short `typedef`ed name than a long template instantiation. But I still think mine's *even* better... :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, declare a global static null pointer.