# How to intentionally delete a boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, shared-ptr

I have many `boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>` objects, and at some point I intentionally want to `delete` some of them to free some memory. (I know at that point that I will never need the pointed-to `MyClass` objects anymore.) How can I do that?

I guess you can't just call `delete()` with the raw pointer that I get with `get()`.

I've seen a function `get_deleter(shared_ptr<T> const & p)` in `boost::shared_ptr`, but I'm not sure how to use it, and also it says *experimental* right next to it. (I think I have Boost 1.38.)

Maybe just assign a new empty `boost::shared_ptr` to the variable? That should throw away the old value and delete it.

Comment: NOOOOO: Don't call delete after a call to get(). The smart pointer still has a copy and will call delete when it releases the object.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You just do

```
ptr.reset();
```

See the [shared_ptr manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). It is equivalent to

```
shared_ptr<T>().swap(ptr)
```

You call `reset` on every smart pointer that should not reference the object anymore. The last such `reset` (or any other action that causes the reference count drop to zero, actually) will cause the object to be free'ed using the deleter automatically.

Maybe you are interested in the [Smart Pointer Programming Techniques](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html). It has an entry about [delayed deallocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#delayed).

Answer (score 9):

If you want to be able to intentionally delete objects (I do all the time) then you have to use single ownership. You have been lured into using shared_ptr when it is not appropriate to your design.

Answer (score 8):

The whole point of `boost::shared_ptr<T>` is that the pointee object will be deleted *exactly* at the moment when no `shared_ptr<T>`s point at it -- that is, when the last `shared_ptr<T>` pointing at this object goes out of scope or is reassigned to point to a different object.  So, all you have to do to delete an object is make sure there are no `shared_ptr<T>`s pointing at it.  E.g. if you only have a single `shared_ptr<T>` called `p` pointing at an object, either let it fall out of scope, or call `p.reset()` (equivalent to `p = NULL` for a plain pointer), or assign it to point at something else.

If you have two `shared_ptr<T>`s pointing at the object, you'll need to reassign both of them.

**EDIT:** Thanks to dehmann for pointing out that `p = NULL;` is not actually valid code for a `shared_ptr<T>`... :)

Comment: Sounds good, but one thing: You can't write p=NULL, because p is a shared_ptr, not a pointer.

Comment: Yes, for a related question on how to use NULL when using shared_ptrs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621220/null-pointer-with-boostsharedptr/621249#621249

Comment: @m-sharp: Thanks for the link. I added an answer on that thread that allows a natural "p = nullPtr;" syntax to be used for any shared_ptr<T> type.

Comment: so why isnt `p = nullptr` syntax allowed? it seems pretty intuitive, more so than `reset()`...

Comment: @jiggunjer: I don't know, but I do know that smart pointers arrived a long time before the keyword `nullptr` was part of the C++ language.  Allowing `p = nullptr` *in addition* seems like it could do no harm...  But then a lot of things seem that way in C++ at first :-/

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is return weak references using [boost::weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) that can be converted to a shared_ptr when needed.  This can allow you to control the lifetime of the object in the shared_ptr and those that want to access it can hold onto the weak_ptr and try to convert to a shared_ptr.  If that convert fails, then they can re-query and bring the object back into memory.