# Deleting content of a boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a doubt with `boost::shared_ptr`.

I have seen this in a destructor (with *ptr* being a boost::shared_ptr):
`ptr = boost::shared_ptr< int >( new int )`.

Is that ok?. Shouldn't it be `ptr.reset()`, like stated here: [How to intentionally delete a boost::shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621233/how-to-intentionally-delete-a-boostshared-ptr)

Cheers!.

Comment: You have a doubt? Where there is doubt, let me sow faith: It's fine.

Comment: Hi, oh divine prophet!. Why is that better than calling `reset()`?. Or is it a matter of taste?. Thanks!.

Comment: It's not better, it's worse. Unless you do want to use that new int, of course.

Comment: Ok!!. Thanks!. How about posting it as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @AdriC.S.: It's not better, but it's also not incorrect. The point of smart pointer classes (or *any* sane library code for that matter) is that you cannot break anything by using its normal interface. Assignment of smart pointers is perfectly fine (though `reset` is clearer and more direct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with ptr afterwards.

If you need to reassign it to point to a new value, then that's what the code does. If you need to explicitly invalidate it, then that's what `reset()` does. If it's a class member that will be implicitly destroyed by the destructor, then there's probably no need to do anything, unless you have some weird destruction order requirements.

Without more context, it's impossible to say which is correct.

**UPDATE:** since you say this is not actually in a destructor, but a member function intended to leave the object in a weird half-destroyed state, it depends on how that weird state is specified. If it requires an empty pointer, then reset it; if it requires a valid pointer, but not to whatever was previously being shared, then reassign it. Better still, eliminate this state entirely to give the object stronger validity guarantees.

Comment: Hi!. Well, for what I've seen, the shared pointer is used inside a class. So when the instance of that class is destroyed, the shared pointer disspears, since each instance has its own shared pointer. The new int line is used in a method called finalize, that's called when the object is destroyed. – Adri C.S. 4 secs ago

Comment: @AdriC.S.: So you have a member function that's intended to put the object into some weird undead state, separately from the destructor? In that case, only the lunatic who designed that class can say what the post-conditions of that function are supposed to be. In a sane design, destruction would be handled by the destructor, and you wouldn't need to do anything explicit to release a `shared_ptr` member.

Comment: Yep, there's the `finalize` function that "clears" the shared pointer and deletes other normal pointers used inside the class. The destuctor is declared... but empty: `~ThatClass::ThatClass(){}`.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: If it's truly meant to "clear" the object without actually destroying it, then you do indeed want `reset()`.

Comment: Mike, thnaks for your answer. Just one more question, what if the object is meant to be destroyed?.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: When the object is destroyed, there's no need to do anything explicit with `shared_ptr` members; they will be implicitly released by their own destructors. You only need to delete anything you're managing with raw pointers - which you really shouldn't be doing at all, ever.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr = boost::shared_ptr< int >( new int )` will swap the internal value with a new int that you don't want to use by calling the `boost::shared_ptr` constructor... in his destructor.

`ptr.reset()` will swap the internal value with nothing, it's better as mentioned in the post you linked