# what does .reset do to a shared_pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I wanted to know what `.reset()` does to a shared pointer. 
Does it simply decrement the reference count of a shared pointer by one as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621233/how-to-intentionally-delete-a-boostshared-ptr) or does it remove all reference counts to an object resetting the count to 0

This is my code sample here

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<foo>> vec;
boost::shared_ptr<foo> f(boost::make_shared<foo>()); //ref count 1
vec.push_back(f); //ref count 1
vec.push_back(f); //ref count 3
int a = f.use_count(); //Will return 3
f.reset();        //Will turn the refernece count to 0
vec[1].reset();   //Will reduce the reference count by 1.
a = f.use_count();
```

I am curious as to why doing `f.reset()` turns the reference count to 0 while `vec[1].reset()` reduces the reference count by 1

Comment: Did you read any docs, or e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It releases the current reference. Other references are not affected.

Comment: @MistyD After you call `f.reset()`, _of course_ `f.use_count()` is 0. It has no reference to anything! But if you call `vec[0].use_count()`, it should have the correct number.