# Default value for boost::shared_ptr on class constructor

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, multiple-constructors

Suppose I have class like

```
class A{
    public:
    A(int a, boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr){
        // whatever!
    }
};
```

My question is, what's the default value for that ptr? I'd like to be able to create an instance of that class using

```
A myA(5);
```

Sure I know I could create another constructor with just one parameter, but I'm looking for something like

```
A(int a, boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr = WAT?)
```

Is it possible? Currently I'm using the two-constructors way, but it would be great to do it this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

A(int a, boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr = boost::make_shared<int>())
```

Check http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't tried to use make_shared that way, even though I was using it when calling that constructor from other places. However, it would be great to have that "ptr" in its default value rather than giving it a dummy value, because I'm not exactly using an integer, but a full-fledged class.

Comment: You can call it without the dummy value, I was just using an example.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621220/null-pointer-with-boostshared-ptr), I can use the shared pointer's default constructor like this:

```
A(int a, boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr = boost::shared_ptr<int>())
```